# PostgreSQL filter by date in current query

Tags: sql, postgresql, filter

Initial data:
[base](https://dropmefiles.com/0C4k0)

There is a database query:

```
SELECT accounts.number acc, counters.service serv, meter_pok.date, counters.tarif, meter_pok.value
    FROM stack.accounts
    LEFT JOIN stack.counters ON counters.acc_id = accounts.row_id
    LEFT JOIN stack.meter_pok ON meter_pok.acc_id = accounts.row_id AND meter_pok.counter_id = counters.row_id
    WHERE accounts.type = 3 AND counters.service = 100
```

that returns the following when executed:

```
"acc","serv","date","tarif","value"
111,100,"2023-01-30",1,100
111,100,"2023-02-25",1,100
122,100,"2023-01-25",1,100
122,100,"2023-02-27",1,50
133,100,"2023-01-25",1,100
133,100,"2023-02-27",1,900
144,100,"2023-02-27",1,0
301,100,"2023-01-25",1,200
301,100,"2023-02-27",1,40
301,100,"2023-02-27",1,-90
501,100,"2023-01-25",1,100
501,100,"2023-02-27",1,50
402,100,NULL,1,NULL
401,100,NULL,1,NULL
502,100,NULL,1,NULL
```

How to add filtering by latest date? To get the following result:

```
"acc","serv","date","tarif","value"
111,100,"2023-02-25",1,100
122,100,"2023-02-27",1,50
133,100,"2023-02-27",1,900
144,100,"2023-02-27",1,0
301,100,"2023-02-27",1,40
301,100,"2023-02-27",1,-90
501,100,"2023-02-27",1,50
```

Tried this query, no result...

```
SELECT accounts.number acc, counters.service serv, meter_pok.date, counters.tarif, meter_pok.value
    FROM stack.accounts
    LEFT JOIN stack.counters ON counters.acc_id = accounts.row_id
    LEFT JOIN stack.meter_pok ON meter_pok.acc_id = accounts.row_id AND meter_pok.counter_id = counters.row_id
    WHERE accounts.type = 3 AND counters.service = 100 AND meter_pok.date = (SELECT MAX(meter_pok.date) FROM stack.meter_pok)
```

Comment: `select max(date) from stack.meter_pok;  2023-02-28`. Look at results of your first query, none of them have a `date = '2023-02-28'::date`. Hence no rows returned.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I believe the OP wants the latest date by `acc`, not the latest date from the `meter_pork` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using Window Functions! To be more specific, using the [DENSE_RANK](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#:%7E:text=its%20peer%20group.-,dense_rank,-()%20%E2%86%92%20bigint) function.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
  accounts.number acc,
  counters.service serv,
  meter_pok.date,
  counters.tarif,
  meter_pok.value,
  DENSE_RANK () OVER (
    PARTITION BY accounts.number
    ORDER BY meter_pok.date DESC
  ) AS row_num
FROM stack.accounts
LEFT JOIN stack.counters ON counters.acc_id = accounts.row_id
LEFT JOIN stack.meter_pok ON meter_pok.acc_id = accounts.row_id AND meter_pok.counter_id = counters.row_id
WHERE accounts.type = 3
AND counters.service = 100
AND date IS NOT NULL
) AS tb
WHERE row_num = 1;
```

Output:

| acc | serv | date | tarif | value | row_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 100 | 2023-02-25 | 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 122 | 100 | 2023-02-27 | 1 | 50 | 1 |
| 133 | 100 | 2023-02-27 | 1 | 900 | 1 |
| 144 | 100 | 2023-02-27 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 301 | 100 | 2023-02-27 | 1 | 40 | 1 |
| 301 | 100 | 2023-02-27 | 1 | -90 | 1 |
| 501 | 100 | 2023-02-27 | 1 | 50 | 1 |

Example on [SQLize](https://sqlize.online/s/14).

Comment: Your query does not work as written.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! I've removed the wrong comma after the PARTITION BY.

Comment: Window Functions are such powerful tools, great answer.

Comment: You can achieve the same thing w/o using a window function.

Comment: Yep, another option would be to get the max date by acc value, then filter the other query using these values. I find Window Functions a more concise way, specially given PostgreSQL support them since version 8.4.

Comment: 1) You don't have to do that either and you would not lose the values as your query does. Run your query and try to find the `301,100,"2023-02-27",1,-90` row the OP wants. 2) The comma is not the only issue. Download the data and test your query.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for pointing that issue! The subquery needed an alias, and to bring multiple records with max date, just needs to replace the `ROW_NUMBER` function with `DENSE_RANK`. I've updated my response and included a link to SQLize. I'm curious though about your proposition, could you provide further details?

Comment: 1) Per your example at SQLize it should be `AS tb`. `AS table` will fail. 2) See [SQLize](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql15/1b19d7fcf2b6b5274981dfeb3a5fb629/).

Comment: 1) Thanks, answer updated. 2) Your query doesn't meet the OP requirements, it brings duplicate records for same `acc` field (e.g. 111) and records with null dates.